# Trying to delete a directory containing certain characters

Tags: python, directory, glob, shutil

Using python, i'm trying to delete any directory with a name containing hard brackets (as well as everything within that directory). (e.g. [dirname], [dirname2]...)

```
import os
import glob 
import shutil # delete an entire dir tree
# get a recursive list of file paths that matches pattern including sub directories
fileList = glob.glob('C:/Users/stef/Desktop/python test folder/[*]', recursive=True)
# Iterate over the list of filepaths & remove each file.
for filePath in fileList:
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(filePath)
    except OSError:
        print("Error while deleting file")
```

Throws out an error regarding 'recursive'. I'm using Python 3.8.5.
TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'

I'd also need help figuring out dry run before executing this script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you could use pathlib.Path.rglob from the the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module.

```
from pathlib import Path

fileList = Path('C:/Users/stef/Desktop/python test folder').rglob('[*]')

for filePath in fileList:
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(filePath)
    except OSError:
        print("Error while deleting file")
```

For drying running I advice to change the line
`shutil.rmtree(filePath)`
to
`print(filePath)`
to see which files would be deleted had the code been run